# Integrate existing Anroid App into React Native Project

Tags: java, android, reactjs, react-native, kotlin

I want to integrate my existing Android and ios projects into react native. So I create a new react native project using expo bare flow. I have followed all the steps mentioned in the official React native document: https://reactnative.dev/docs/integration-with-existing-apps?language=kotlin

This is my MainActivity code, which just navigates to RNModuleActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val btnGoRNScreen = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button)
        btnGoRNScreen.setOnClickListener {
            
            val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, RNModuleActivity::class.java)
            intent.putExtra("message_from_native", "yes")
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

My RNModuleActivity code:

```
class RNModuleActivity : Activity(), DefaultHardwareBackBtnHandler {
    private lateinit var reactRootView: ReactRootView
    private lateinit var reactInstanceManager: ReactInstanceManager
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        SoLoader.init(this, false)
        reactRootView = ReactRootView(this)
        val packages: List<ReactPackage> = PackageList(application).packages
        // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
        // packages.add(MyReactNativePackage())
        // Remember to include them in `settings.gradle` and `app/build.gradle` too.
        reactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(application)
            .setCurrentActivity(this)
            .setBundleAssetName("index.android.bundle")
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackages(packages)
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build()
        
        // the string in AppRegistry.registerComponent() in index.js
        reactRootView?.startReactApplication(reactInstanceManager, "testapp", null)
        setContentView(reactRootView)
    }

    override fun invokeDefaultOnBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostPause(this)
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostResume(this, this)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        reactInstanceManager.onHostDestroy(this)
        reactRootView.unmountReactApplication()
    }

    override fun onBackPressed() {
        reactInstanceManager.onBackPressed()
        super.onBackPressed()
    }

    override fun onKeyUp(keyCode: Int, event: KeyEvent?): Boolean {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU && reactInstanceManager != null) {
            reactInstanceManager.showDevOptionsDialog()
            return true
        }
        return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event)
    }
}
```

I have set the default activity to MainActivity in my manifest file. But when I click on the button to navigate to RNModuleActivity it returns this error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.jscexecutor.JSCExecutor.loadLibrary(JSCExecutor.java:24)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.getDefaultJSExecutorFactory(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:363)
                                                                                                        at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.build(ReactInstanceManagerBuilder.java:316)
                                                                                                        at com.krytron.RNModuleActivity.onCreate
```